# Asp.net Core, MemoryCache & CacheExtensions of "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" are thread safe type or not?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching

Asp.net Core, MemoryCache & CacheExtensions of "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" are thread safe types or not?

I'm going over lot of documents but cant able to conclude as it is confusing. Some expertise opinion would helpful.

Comment: although the documentation does not state it clearly but it should be thread-safe otherwise you cannot use it conveniently. And here the source code of some archived version https://github.com/aspnet/caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs - you can see internally a `ConcurrentDictionary` is used.

Comment: have you been through this? https://blog.novanet.no/asp-net-core-memory-cache-is-get-or-create-thread-safe/

Comment: looks like it takes the tradeoff between possibility of being locked & performance. Usually your cached data should be consistent in a short time (so that even when the race condition occurs, there may be a bit or no difference among the results returned from the cache). After that short period of race condition, the key is already cached with one value and it will then work fine.

Comment: I missed that point in the documentation talking about the possible race condition that causes the factory code to run multiple times (which may return different results). It's not kind of fully thread-safe as we usually expect.

Comment: if you load a large data into a cache that may spend some long time, you should write your custom logic to avoid multiple times executing the loading logic (which may consume the system resources considerably).